# DFS and BFS Outputs?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

So I'm confused with the outputs of both of the BFS and DFS algorithms.

As much as I understood BFS takes as input a graph suppose `G` and a vertex suppose `x`.

Output : returns a graph, which in for every vertex in `G`, the new graph
has the shortest way from vertex `x` to any other vertex in the graph.

is that right? if not, what is?

and how about DFS ? DFS's input is only a graph, does it mean DFS doesn't care where you start from? and what's DFS's Output?

Thanks

Comment: It's just two approaches to traverse graph using linear data structures (queue for BFS, stack for DFS). There is no definition of their "output".

Comment: If BFS and DFS both travel through a graph and find the shortest way, then i can just add my own piece of code to the algorithm to store the data? i mean to remember shortest paths?

Comment: I didn't said that. DFS can't find shortest path in unweighed graph, just BFS. If you need the code that searches shortest path with BFS - google it, test it, use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what it is that you wanted, but I'll give it a shot.

Let's say we have the following graph:

```
X - 1 - 2 - 3
| \
1  1
|   \
2    2
|     \
3      3
```

In this graph, X marks the node where we will start traversing from, and a number denotes a value that a particular node holds. This time X has 3 immediate neighboring nodes, that all hold a value 1.

For the sake of the example, let us assume that any node cannot be traversed twice. Let us also assume that the program always prints the value of the node it's standing on.

Without really getting in depth with the way BFS and DFS work (at all), the output would be like this:

```
BFS: X 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
DFS: X 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the input, ya i like this example and that's exactly what i thought the output would be. so I got more confident now seeing your comment and matching your output with my expectations, thanks!

Comment: @ShlomiMizrahi Glad I could help. Would you mark this answer as the solution (green sign next to the post) if you are satisfied with it :)

Answer (score 0):

DFS is a Graph traversal technique which takes the graph and a starting vertex(random) as input and gives a sequence of vertices as output.
The sequence contains those vertices which are reachable from the starting vertex.
i.e we are  finding whether any vertex is reachable from any other vertex in a graph or not?